# Time after time

Tags: riddle, rhyme, acrostic

It's been a while since my last visit to the Puzzling.SE community; I hope everyone has been doing well and that everyone has an exciting and happy new year! For those of you who are sitting at home bored, drunk, or just enjoy the site as much as I do, here's another riddle! As always, good luck to all of you!

> Six stars falling, three at a time,
>
> Hundreds of people, now speaking in rhyme.
>
> Seventy-three more, let's find what you seek,
>
> Contained in this rhyme, broke but not bleak.

---

The correct answer will explain the acrostic. Also, keep in mind that I don't always keep to traditional acrostics.

---

### Hints

> The acrostic not letters, but words yes indeed; it's really quite simple, the first three you need.

Comment: The acrostic is obviously the last letter of each line.  or "eekk"!  slightly misspelled, but appropriate for my thoughts while I try to decipher :)  Happy New Year

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I found an answer that adds to what has already been guessed:

The acrostic seems to be

> (as already has been guessed by Quintec)
>
>  Six
>  Hundred
>  Seventy-Three
>  Contained
>  =673

But the riddle contains some more information.

Six stars falling, three at a time

> If we multiply the number 673 **times three** we get 2019

Hundreds of people, now speaking in rhyme.

> This could be referring to New Years Eve or Christmas since those are holidays that get rhymed about a lot.

Seventy-three more, let's find what you seek,

> I do not know if that line is supposed to tell us something or if it just constructed for the purpose of adding the number 73

Contained in this rhyme, broke but not bleak.

> That ending sounds like there's still a little more to this ... but I could not think of anything plausible yet.
>  All in all I'd still say the riddle is just a creative way of wishing the people of SE a Happy New Year 2019

Answer (score 2):

If you

> take the first word of each line, you get "673 contained". I think this means that there are 673 characters in the puzzle, which means the answer is CHARACTERS, which fits the "hundreds of people" line in the riddle (character in book, etc.)

Comment: Nice try, and you've found the acrostic, but you're missing a vital piece of information from the riddle as a whole, find the relation and you'll find the answer. +1

Comment: If you use a bit of multiplication hinted at the first line, you get something that would qualify this question for the [tag:seasonal] tag, and would fit the title too. No idea if that's the intended answer, but it looks too convenient to be a coinky dink.

Comment: @Bass I’m aftaid I’m not quite sure what you’re trying to say

Comment: @Bass You’re definitely thinking the right way there.